# How to deploy Kafka on Azure Web App service

Tags: azure, docker, apache-kafka, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone have idea how to set Kafka to works on Azure Web App service?
I have tried by creating docker container and pulling image to Azure but Azure Web app service wont be running.
By the why, whether deploying Kafka to Azure Web service is a good approach?

Comment: Why are you trying to run Kafka as a web application? It's not a web application. It would be a better fit in Azure Container Instances or in a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Seems like you're asking the exact same question. If you have any updates to your previous post, please edit it. But as written there and here, Kafka and Zookeeper are not "web apps"

Comment: Yes, same but in a different way. Maybe I am doing something totally wrong, and I would like hear whether other had experience with deploying Kafka on Azure Web App service and how they done it. I kindly ask you not to mark this question as duplicate because in the first one I am showing where I am stuck and here I want to hear others and their experience with Kafka and Azure.